# Understanding Precision parameter in Select By Location tool of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

Is there anybody that can tell what is the purpose of having a "Precision" parameter on
Vector | Research Tools | Select by Location?

Where I can find or read about how this "Precision" parameter works?

I'm using QGIS 2.16.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: This might have some insight: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/2341

Comment: thanks.... there is not much information about this.

Comment: I ran it with test data but results are unclear.  Setting precision as 0.001 makes no difference in selecting point features (intersection predicate) along a polygon's boundary.  Changing precision to 0.01 made the selection of point feature over the poly bnd.  But those same numbers did not work on point/line intersection test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a lot of detail available but from the [SelectByLocation.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByLocation.py) script, it seems to be used for the `snapToPrecision()` function (again barely any information on this) which requires the feature geometry and a real number as input.

This is then used to create a **buffered bounding box** of the features for the intersection part.

Comment: using SQL function st_snap(geoma,geomb,0.001) does the trick of selecting points that lie over boundaries, but this is not part of qgis' select by location algorithm.  What would be nice to have in qgis would be a 'buffer' parameter like ArcGIS.

Comment: @IvánSantiago - You can always add a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) :)