# Define precision in geometric predicate methods in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, intersection, select, overlay, select-by-location

It is possible to define precision for geometric predicate methods, such as:

`intersects ()`, `contains ()`, `equals ()`, `touches ()`, `overlaps ()`, `within ()`, `crosses()`

For example, I'd like to set the precision in this situation:

`feat_to_select.geometry().intersects(selected_feat.geometry())`

Comment: What to you mean by "precision"?

Comment: @ YoLecomte The answer to your question can be found here [link ][1] [1]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211130/82192

Comment: @JaymeMuzzy Ok! So see my answer. Can you also close your previous question by accepting (click on the tick below votes) an answer? Because it will remains unanswered if you don't do that. Thk's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extend the geometry by adding a buffer:

```
precision = 0.1 #adjust to your need (in map unit)
feat_to_select.geometry().intersects(selected_feat.geometry().buffer(precision))
```